# Saving a word document creates a new document in Android (Dex Mode)

Tags: android, save

Each time i open an existing word document(let's say its called filename) (I'm using office suite app - Samsung Dex) and make modification to it, when i try to save the file, a save as window is displayed which results in the creation of a new document (filename(1), if i don't enter a new name) instead of applying the save to the original document.

Now, when i close the resulting filename(1), then open that file and apply change to it, saving would result in the display of save as window and the creation of filnename(1)(1), and this process repeats each time i close, open, then modify a resulting document.

I tried using other word apps like wps office, I expected the save to apply to the original file, but i got the same problem, any help is highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask because Stackoverflow is about programming only. You have to ask at https://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It has to do with the file location. My file was stored in my SD Card at first, I moved it to Phone Storage and autosave started to work. Try moving the file to a location with a shorter file path. With the file open in Word, tap the 3 dots > tap Save, you'll be able to see the Autosave setting.